# Custom tree cell editing in a SwingX JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swingx, jxtreetable

I'm trying to set a custom tree cell editor for the tree column of a `JXTreeTable`, but for some reason, my editor is never called.

Here's the bit that is supposed to set the editor:

`dataTable.setDefaultEditor(DataEntity.class, new NumberedListEditor(hierarchyRelation));`

My implementation of `getColumnClass()` returns `DataEntity.class` and I overrode `isCellEditable()` in my model to always return `true`.

What else could be the problem?

Comment: if you want that custom editor in the hierarchical column - that's not cleanly possible currently (see http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1272 which has a link to a workaround) If it's on another column, somehting else is wrong, please show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I may have found that out the hard way. I ended up doing exactly what the workaround suggested. I never saw the default `TreeTableTextField` editor but that may be because my rendering component isn't a JLabel. It's a JRenderingPanel with two JLabels inside of it. Now I'm trying to override setBounds() to draw the editor in the right place (pretty much exactly how TreeTableTextField does it) but with minimal success. Thanks a bunch   for your quick answer!

Comment: @kleopatra : Could you please explain in some detail about the solution that you have explained here - java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1272 . I tried the same thing but no effect...You can see my question at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909379/jxtreetable-custom-cell-editor

Comment: @kleopatra Workaround link on the JIRA is changed or dead, do you have new link?

Comment: no, sorry, kenai is dead :-(

Answer (score 0):

setDefaultEditor() works for me:

```
tbl_attribute.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new FeatureSearchAttributeTreeCellEditor());
```